# Formik validation doesn't validate Email input

Tags: react-native, formik

I've done a [simple App](https://blog.jscrambler.com/creating-and-validating-react-native-forms-with-formik) to learn more about Formik.
But when I run it, **the Schema doesn't validate the e-mail input**, I don't really know why.

LoginSchema.js:

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const LoginSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email('Invalid email').required('Required'),
    password: Yup.string()
        .min(2, 'Too Short!')
        .max(10, 'Too Long!')
        .required('Required')
});

export default LoginSchema;
```

Login.js

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';

import TextInput from '../components/TextInput';
import Button from '../components/Button';
import LoginSchema from '../schema/LoginSchema'

export default function Login() {
  const password = useRef(null);
  const { handleChange, handleSubmit, handleBlur, values, errors, touched } = useFormik({
    validationSchema: LoginSchema,
    initialValues: { email: '', password: '' },
    onSubmit: values =>
      alert(`Email: ${values.email}, Password: ${values.password}`)
  });
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
      }}
    >
      <Text style={{ color: '#223e4b', fontSize: 20, marginBottom: 16 }}>
        Login
      </Text>
      <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 32, marginBottom: 16, width: '100%' }}>
        <TextInput
          icon='mail'
          placeholder='Enter your email'
          onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
          onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
          onSubmitEditing={() => password.current?.focus()}
          errors={errors.email}
          touched={touched.email}
          autoCapitalize='none'
          autoCompleteType='email'
          keyboardType='email-address'
          keyboardAppearance='dark'
          returnKeyType='next'
          returnKeyLabel='next'
        />
      </View>
      <View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 32, marginBottom: 16, width: '100%' }}>
        <TextInput
          ref={password}
          icon='key'
          placeholder='Enter your password'
          onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
          onBlur={handleBlur('password')}
          onSubmitEditing={() => handleSubmit()}
          error={errors.password}
          touched={touched.password}
          secureTextEntry
          autoCompleteType='password'
          autoCapitalize='none'
          keyboardAppearance='dark'
          returnKeyType='go'
          returnKeyLabel='go'
        />
      </View>
      <Button label='Login' onPress={handleSubmit} />
    </View>
  );
}
```

As you can see in the image below, only the password input is validated:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0j7O.png)

I've tried to add more validations to the LoginSchema email, to see what happens, but it seems that the Login.js doesn't recognize the email validation at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is error in the `TextInput` :

```
<View style={{ paddingHorizontal: 32, marginBottom: 16, width: '100%' }}>
        <TextInput
          icon='mail'
          placeholder='Enter your email'
          onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
          onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
          onSubmitEditing={() => password.current?.focus()}
          error={errors.email} //HERE: change errors to error in your code
          touched={touched.email}
          autoCapitalize='none'
          autoCompleteType='email'
          keyboardType='email-address'
          keyboardAppearance='dark'
          returnKeyType='next'
          returnKeyLabel='next'
        />
      </View>
```

Comment: It's okay !!  sometimes happened . Also if you think this answer solve your queries,please accept this as this would really motivates me to help other's in  stackoverflow. Thank you !!